# Why isn't my SqlDataSource's UpdateCommand working?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="HopefulDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand= "SELECT id, regGroupID, amountReceived, other FROM table" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE table
                        SET [amountReceived] = @amountReceived
                        WHERE [regGroupID] = @regGroupID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCourses" Name="ddlSelectedCourse" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="regGroupID"        Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="amountReceived"    Type="Decimal" />

        other parameters

        <asp:Parameter Name="id"                Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The above works when I change "WHERE [regGroupID] = @regGroupID" to either

WHERE [id] = @id

or

WHERE [regGroupID] = 2

Comment: How are you setting the value of your regGroupID parameter?

Comment: Through a GridView row edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add "regGroupID" to the `DataKeyNames` collection in your `GridView` declaration.  Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="yourGridViewId" DataKeyNames="regGroupID" ... >
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

See the [`DataKeyNames` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx):

> You must set the DataKeyNames property in order for the automatic
>   update and delete features of the GridView control to work. The values
>   of these key fields are passed to the data source control in order to
>   specify the row to update or delete.

Note: it's been a while since I used this, so you might need to include both the primary key, and your other key field.  Like this:

```
DataKeyNames="id,regGroupID"
```

Comment: You! You're a good person. Thank you so much for this! It defaulted to having just id, but adding regGoupID ended hours and hours of work! I both hate and love when one little thing fixes a HUGE problem!

Cheers!

Comment: @statue I totally know what you mean.  And you're welcome, I'm glad to help.